# How to prevent an optional input field's placeholder value from entering into the database on leaving it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a JSP registration form in my site. Also I have a text box with `placeholder="opt"` and `id="ext"` in my JSP registration page which is an optional field. On clicking submit button the value of placeholder is submitting to the database on leaving the optional field blank. But I want to clear the value of text box on leaving it blank. I've tried the below methods. But those methods are not working in my case.

```
document.getElementById("ext").value="";

document.getElementById("ext").placeholder="";

document.getElementById("ext").setAttribute("placeholder","");
```

I've also tried the same methods with jQuery. That also is not working.
Can anybody suggest a solution.

Comment: where is your `<input>` code with placeholder="value"?

Comment: Why not do this in your business logic?

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="opt" id="ext">

Comment: This value is a field in the registration form

Comment: The `placeholder` value is not submitted. If it seems to being submitted, there is some code on the page that causes that (or your server-side logic behaves as if it were submitted, e.g. due to having a default value coinciding with it).

Comment: default value is not applied to the textbox

Comment: Maybe you are using some kind of _polyfill_ to support the `placeholder` attribute in older browsers? Those usually work by setting the `value` attribute when the field is empty …

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the value of placeholder entering into DB b having a condition on `servlet` (business logic) i.e the page handling the DB operations.

Check on servlet like as below:

```
if(request.getParameter("<Parameter name Here>").equals("<Plaeholder value>"))     
{
    // set value of <Parameter name Here> nullhere
    // Do insert option here
}
```

The solution will be valid untill you wil change the placeholder's value.